# What does .. at the start of filepath do?

Tags: directory, filepath

What does ..\ at the start of a file path do?

Example: The following file is referenced in the directory

\work\QA\Reports\TimeOff.rpt

What is the difference between referencing the file path as \work\QA\Reports\TimeOff.rpt and referencing the file path as ..\work\QA\Reports\TimeOff.rpt?

Comment: I don't see why this question was downvoted four years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`..` refers to the parent directory, the directory one level up from the current directory. Additionally, `.` refers to the current directory.

Say you're in directory `\a\b\c\`. You want to access file `\a\b\c\d`. You can access that file with just `d` or `.\d` or `\a\b\c\d`. Say you now want file `\a\b\x`. You can access that as `..\x` or the full absolute path. You can, of course, chain `.` and `..`, like `..\.\..\y`.

Paths starting with `\` are absolute (or `<drive letter>:\`); they refer to the same file every time and don't depend on the current directory. Other paths are relative, the file they refer to changes with the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

it's the difference between relative and absolute path referencing.

```
\work\QA\Reports\TimeOff.rpt
```

starts with a (back)slash "\" (or "/" in unix if it matters), so it's indicating "Start at the root, or top most level directory".
Then navigate down.
It's an `Absolute` path reference.  It doesn't matter where you are, you will always end up pointing to the same file/location.

```
.\work\QA\Reports\TimeOff.rpt
```

however, begins with "." Which is `Relative` path reference. It says to "start where you currently are". so if you were already in folder: `\my\home\directory`
then you'll end up navigating to:

```
\my\home\directory\work\QA\Reports\TimeOff.rpt
```

".." is a reference to go one level up ... but again "relative path".
so:

```
..\work\QA\Reports\TimeOff.rpt
```

if you were in `\my\home\directory`
you'd end up here:

```
\my\home\work\QA\Reports\TimeOff.rpt
```

Since it backs up one level ("\directory\") ..and goes from there.

Hope that makes sense ;)

Answer (score 0):

It means go to parent folder first and then look for the path specified.

so it is basically the same when you do `cd ..` in command line.

The difference between `\work\QA\Reports\TimeOff.rpt` and `..\work\QA\Reports\TimeOff.rpt` is thet if you're in `\a\b` folder, first one will match `\a\b\work\QA\Reports\TimeOff.rpt` and second one `a\work\QA\Reports\TimeOff.rpt`.